# Is Canvas available for Kibana Opendistro Elastic Search?

Tags: canvas, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I could not find Canvas option while working on Kibana opendistro elastic stack. Is it not available or do I have to add it from somewhere? I am new to Data Visualization in Kibana and saw Canvas features and wanted to try in my work but Canvas feature is missing.

Answer (score 1):

No, Canvas is one of the features that is only available in the Elastic default binaries but not Opendistro. Though it is a free feature, so you can download the right binaries and give it a try with them.